# Clang static analyzer flags rvalue reference bound to a temporary?

Tags: c++11, clang, rvalue-reference, clang++, clang-static-analyzer

With the new Xcode 7.0 GM (Apple LLVM version 7.0), the clang static analyser flags the following code as "called C++ object pointer is uninitialized".

```
auto&& x = T();
x.hello(); // issue at this point
```

However I'm pretty sure the rvalue reference `x` extends the lifetime of the temporary constructed by `T()`, so the `x` at the marked line is definitely still alive. I can confirm this at runtime by getting the constructors and destructors to log their calls.

Also if I substitute `const auto& x = T();`, the issue also goes away. I would do that myself but the exact issue is rather to a range-for loop, so I can't change the nature of the reference.

Is the analyzer over-zealous here?

See the reference initialization rules: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization

Comment: Is `T` a type or a function?

Comment: "I can confirm this at runtime by getting the constructors and destructors to log their calls."  That is the final word, and what I would have answered with had you not already done this detective work.  Sounds to me like you've found a bug in the clang static analyzer.

Comment: I think static analyzer has a bug here: I have opened a ticket to track this: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24795

Comment: @Barry `T` is a type, so `T()` is a constructor call. However if I declare a function `f` that returns a `T`, then substituting `f()` for `T()` also fixes the marked line.

Comment: @GlenLow Yeah, but if it was a function that returned a reference to a temporary... then the analyzer would be correct. Hence my question. You posted an incomplete example.